# Shows invalid line number in aar

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have an `AAR` project, and after every release I will be integrating it in to another application, we have enabled proguard for both host application and aar, and we have it working fine.

The problem is when we get any crash report from aar, we are not able to understand the cause and from it happened since the proguard is enabled, this issue happens only for crashes in aar. I have added rules for showing the line number and all but it is showing wrong line number.

Can any one help here ?

Comment: When you say that Proguard is enabled for both, does it mean that the AAR gets obfuscated and built and then added to the other project and that one is also obfuscated? Is the mapping file from the AAR available so it gets uploaded to Crashlytics?

Comment: Yes, aar is obfuscated and aded to other project. and yes mapping files of aar is available.

Comment: or can we have the proguard disabled for aar and enable it in the host application ? that way is also possible